# Help compiling a silverlight project!

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight

Hi every body
I try to compile my project' but I get this error:

> Error  1   The "ValidateXaml" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Documents and Settings\arielih\My Documents\Downloads\פרויקט\RubikCube\obj\Debug\RubikCube.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)
>   File name: 'file:///C:\Documents and Settings\arielih\My Documents\Downloads\פרויקט\RubikCube\obj\Debug\RubikCube.dll' ---> System.NotSupportedException: An attempt was made to load an assembly from a network location which would have caused the assembly to be sandboxed in previous versions of the .NET Framework. This release of the .NET Framework does not enable CAS policy by default, so this load may be dangerous. If this load is not intended to sandbox the assembly, please enable the loadFromRemoteSources switch. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569 for more information.
>
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>
> at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)
>
> at Microsoft.Silverlight.Build.Tasks.ValidateXaml.XamlValidator.Execute(ITask task)
>
> at Microsoft.Silverlight.Build.Tasks.ValidateXaml.XamlValidator.Execute(ITask task)
>
> at Microsoft.Silverlight.Build.Tasks.ValidateXaml.Execute()
>
> at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>
> at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, Boolean& taskResult)
>
> RubikCube

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you downloaded the file RubikCube from the internet, it may be blocked.  Right click on it in the explorer and "unblock it" in the file properties.